# Android Kotlin Get Value of Selected Spinner Item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

I'm using `AndroidStudio 4.1.1` and `kotlin`

I'm having issues trying to get the value of a selected item in a spinner view/item.  My first attempt, and many threads say to do it this way, is:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.wMuscleGroup) as Spinner
val selectedText = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
```

This does not work for me.  `selectedText` shows nothing in a `Toast` or a `println`

I also tried this, which I also found many threads for:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.wMuscleGroup) as Spinner

if (spinner != null) {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, muscleGroups )
    spinner.adapter = adapter

    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
          override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selectedText = muscleGroups[position]
                println("Muscle Group selected is $selectedText")  // <-- this works
          }

         override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
            // write code to perform some action
         }
     }
}

// selectedText is not seen here:
println("Muscle Group selected is $selectedText")
```

This works and I can see `selectedString` in my println, in the `onItemSelected` function inside the block.  But, how do I get this value to be seen outside of this block of code?  I need to use this value in a class object and a database write.  I've tried declaring `selectedString` outside/above the `if (spinner != null)`, but that does not seem to work either.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spinner does not have a value selected by default. Hence calling `spinner.getSelectedItem()` returns `null` and `null.toString()` returns an empty String.

Your code will work only if the user has selected an option from the Spinner first. You can set a initial value by using `spinner.setSelection(position)`.

If you want to use the selected value outside the selection, you can use a global variable as follows:

```
val spinner = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.wMuscleGroup) as Spinner
var selectedText = muscleGroups.first() // as default

if (spinner != null) {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter( this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, muscleGroups )
    spinner.adapter = adapter

    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
          override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedText = muscleGroups[position]
          }

         override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am using an emulator with my app.  I run it and select an item from the spinner in my view.  That is how I am checking it.  I can see the value I select inside the onItemSelected function, via the println.  If the value is there, how can I pass it to something outside the if (spinner != null)?

Comment: You can store it in a global variable and set the variable whenever the user selects an item in the spinner.

Comment: I have added an example of storing it in a global variable

Comment: Thanks, @Subhrajyoti Sen  That is exactly what I needed.  I thought I had declared the var outside the if() block, but probably did something wrong.  Yours works great !!

Comment: Actually after testing this answer, I found it does not work.  selectedText does get changed inside the if() block.  frustrating

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. What are you trying to achieve? selectedText is supposed to get changed when the user selects something in the spinner

Comment: My apologies.  You were correct.  I had this this inside an onClickListener for my Submit button.  I somehow reverted/removed the onClickListener code.  It is working now.  So sorry for MY confusion.  I looked at it so long I could not see what was missing.  I was too focused on why the value wasn't getting stored in the var.  Sigh!!  All good now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try something with selectedText, you should use it inside onItemSelected function.